# Работа c json в angular2

Tags: json, typescript, angular2

Здравствуйте.
Как распарсить json  в ангуляр 2?
Я получаю get запросом вот этот файл: http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts
Записываю его в переменную response типа - string.

Если я вывожу `{{ response }}`, то получаю `[object Object],[object Object],...`
Если `{{ response | json }}`, то получаю просто текст.

Как мне с него получать и выводить на страницу "title" и "body"??

post.component.ts

```
import { Input, Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpService } from './http.service';

@Component ({
    selector: 'news-post',
    templateUrl: './app/news/post.component.html',
    inputs: ['posts'],
    providers: [HttpService]
})


export class NewsPostsComponent {
    response: string;

    constructor(private _httpService: HttpService) {
        this._httpService.getPosts()
            .subscribe(
                response => this.response = response,
                error => console.log(error)
            );
    }
}
```

http.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class HttpService{
    constructor(private _http: Http){}

    getPosts(): Observable<any> {
        return this._http.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
            .map(res => res.json());
    }
}
```

post.component.html

```
<div class="ui main text container">
    <h1 class="ui header">Title</h1>
    <p>Description</p>
    <hr>
</div>
```

Comment: добавляй код, как получаешь и что именно используешь

Comment: @Grundy добавил

Comment: _Если {{ response | json }}, то получаю просто текст._ - а что ты хотел получать?

Comment: @Grundy, ну я просто написал

Comment: смотри, ты получаешь массив. у массива нет свойств "title" и "body" они есть у элементов. Тебе нужно вывести все элементы? или только для какого-то конкретного?

Comment: @Grundy все елементы

Comment: @Roman Kravets внутри вашего дива используйте `<div  *ngFor="let nw of posts">
    <h1 class="ui header">{{nw.title}}</h1>
    <hr>
</div>`

Comment: @MrFylypenko, у него в коде нигде не устанавливается `posts`

Comment: @Grundy, это я забыл его удалить, у меня раньше был двухмерный масив

Comment: Всё, спарсил, просто я не думал что это масив

Comment: но это массив :-)

Comment: @Grundy а я думал что с обьектами как-то по другому нужно работать

Comment: а у тебя там нет объектов же, только массив с объектами, ну и раз уж typescript дает типы - лучше их использовать вместо `any`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="ui main text container" *ngFor="let nw of response">
    <h1 class="ui header">{{ nw.title }}</h1>
    <p>{{ nw.body }}</p>
    {{ nw.userId }}
    <hr>
</div>
```